# MASM: Invalid use of register when passing to macro

Tags: assembly, x86, masm

I'm quite new to MASM and am attempting to complete an exercise using a macro, however, every time I try to pass a parameter to the macro, I receive the error `error A2032: invalid use of register`. As far as I can tell, I'm using the macro correctly. Is this a configuration problem? The gist of the portion of my code that seems to be causing the issue is below. The macro is called within a separate procedure, to which parameters are passed on the stack.

```
mDoThing MACRO temp
  push edx
  push ecx
  mov edx,offset stringToWrite
  call WriteString
  mov edx,offset temp
  mov ecx,MAXSIZE
  call ReadString
  pop ecx
  pop edx
ENDM

.code 

main PROC

push offset arrayToFill
push offset strBuffer
call ReadVal


main ENDP

ReadVal PROC

  push ebp
  mov  ebp,esp
  mov edx,[ebp+8]  ; strBuffer

  mDoThing edx    ; trying to use macro here

  .... etc

ReadVal ENDP
```

Comment: You pass `edx` as `temp` argument and the macro will try to apply `offset temp` to it which is invalid as registers don't have addresses. PS: avoid macros whenever possible and consider using a function instead.

Comment: Ah. Googling along those lines reveals a lot of info I can use. Thanks.